# What's the best way to parse a file with header line format in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, file, parsing, markdown

Given that I have a custom file with a format like:

```
-- Title: title that will be displayed (independent from filename)
-- Author: Jhon Doe
-- Date: someday
-- ... more similar tags that may not exist on each file ...

# Rest of the file in a Mardown Format

* Item 1 example
* Item 2
  * Item 2a
  * Item 2b
```

how can i parse the content parse it using something like:

```js
var fs = require('fs')

const parse = (content) => {
  "parsing happens here"
  return {title, author, date, article}
}

fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', (err, data) =>{
  if (err) throw err;
  return parse(data)
});
```

Comment: define whats separates the two sections (2 `\n`'s), then split by it then parse the top section https://playcode.io/823052/ though really depends on how robust you want it, a better solution might be to wrap params in 2 `---`'s like how [nuxt/content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/writing#front-matter) does it, then you can simply split by the second `---` and parse with yaml

Comment: I did reverse engineering  on nuxt/content, it's called a front matter block, I can only use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/front-matter and my job is done!. Thanks